# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.py'; 'app' is not a package when deploying on render

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deployment

I've been trying to upload my prediction model as a web app using render based on an ML deployment template provided in one of my classes.

I've tried to mostly follow the example I was given, except for #3 in the app.py file that's unique to my model (the repo I've made can be found here):
https://github.com/kaigg96/The-Advantage-of-Being-Small-A-Model-for-Individual-Investors/tree/main

Trying to deploy the model using Render is producing the following error:

```
...
Jul 16 02:54:59 PM  Successfully installed Flask-2.2.5 Flask-WTF-1.1.1 Jinja2-3.1.2 MarkupSafe-2.1.3 WTForms-3.0.1 Werkzeug-2.2.3 appdirs-1.4.4 beautifulsoup4-4.12.2 certifi-2023.5.7 charset-normalizer-3.2.0 click-8.1.5 cycler-0.11.0 datetime-5.1 fonttools-4.38.0 frozendict-2.3.8 gunicorn-20.1.0 html5lib-1.1 idna-3.4 importlib-metadata-6.7.0 itsdangerous-2.1.2 joblib-1.3.1 kiwisolver-1.4.4 lightgbm-4.0.0 lxml-4.9.3 matplotlib-3.5.3 multitasking-0.0.11 numexpr-2.8.4 numpy-1.21.6 packaging-23.1 pandas-1.3.5 pillow-9.5.0 pyparsing-3.1.0 python-dateutil-2.8.2 pytz-2023.3 requests-2.31.0 scikit-learn-1.0.2 scipy-1.7.3 seaborn-0.12.2 six-1.16.0 soupsieve-2.4.1 tables-3.7.0 threadpoolctl-3.1.0 typing-extensions-4.7.1 urllib3-2.0.3 webencodings-0.5.1 yfinance-0.2.24 zipp-3.15.0 zope.interface-6.0
Jul 16 02:54:59 PM  WARNING: You are using pip version 20.1.1; however, version 23.2 is available.
Jul 16 02:54:59 PM  You should consider upgrading via the '/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/python -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
Jul 16 08:27:36 PM  ==> Uploading build...
Jul 16 08:27:49 PM  ==> Build uploaded in 10s
Jul 16 08:27:49 PM  ==> Build successful 
Jul 16 08:27:49 PM  ==> Deploying...
Jul 16 08:28:11 PM  ==> Using Node version 14.17.0 (default)
Jul 16 08:28:11 PM  ==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
Jul 16 08:28:16 PM  ==> Starting service with 'gunicorn app.py'
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 359, in import_app
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      mod = importlib.import_module(module)
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 962, in _find_and_load_unlocked
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'app.py'; 'app' is not a package
```

I've tried changing everything I can think of, but ultimately am not familiar enough with Flask or Render to figure out what the issue is... Further down in the deploy log it gives the following error, before repeating these errors a few times until the deployment finally fails.

````
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  Traceback (most recent call last):
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/bin/gunicorn", line 8, in <module>
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      sys.exit(run())
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 67, in run
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      WSGIApplication("%(prog)s [OPTIONS] [APP_MODULE]").run()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 231, in run
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      super().run()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 72, in run
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      Arbiter(self).run()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 58, in __init__
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      self.setup(app)
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 118, in setup
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      self.app.wsgi()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      self.callable = self.load()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 58, in load
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      return self.load_wsgiapp()
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 48, in load_wsgiapp
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM    File "/opt/render/project/src/.venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 363, in import_app
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM      raise ImportError(msg % (module.rsplit(".", 1)[0], obj))
Jul 16 08:28:25 PM  ImportError: Failed to find application, did you mean 'app:application'?```

In response I've tried modifying the Procfile to web: gunicorn app:application, but that produces the same error.

Any help is appreciated, thank you!
````